# Method that creates characters

Tags: c#, class

I'm new to programming so I'm trying to make a very simple rpg battle simulator for programming practice and I've run into a problem when creating the characters. When I make my characters in the main program they work fine, I can interact with them exactly how I want. It makes the main program look very ugly though so my idea was that id have a method that creates all the characters for me:

```
class Create
{
    public static void Characters()
    {
        Hero Dash = new Hero("Dash", 3, 10);

        Bandit Keith = new Bandit("Keith", 1, 5);
        Bandit Leader = new Bandit("Bandit Leader", 2, 8);

        Knight Leeroy = new Knight("Leeroy" , 3, 12);
        Knight Seth = new Knight("Seth", 5, 15);

        Dragon BlueDrag = new Dragon("Blue Dragon", 7, 20, 2);
        Dragon RedDrag = new Dragon("Red Dragon", 8, 20, 3);
        Dragon BlackDrag = new Dragon("BlackDrag", 10, 25, 4);
    }
}
```

However I can't use them. For example if I try to make Dash attack something using my attack method , it says Dash doesn't exist in the current context. Why does this happen? Thank you. Sorry if this is a really dumb question.

Comment: Do some searching about variable scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code below.  It would probably be better to create a dictionary where you can look up characters by a string name instead of creating a variable for each character.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Create.Characters();
            Dragon BlackDrag = Create.BlackDrag;
        }
    }
    public class Create
    {
        public static Hero Dash { get; set; }

        public static Bandit Keith { get; set; }
        public static Bandit Leader { get; set; }

        public static Knight Leeroy { get; set; }
        public static Knight Seth { get; set; }

        public static Dragon BlueDrag { get; set; }
        public static Dragon RedDrag { get; set; }
        public static Dragon BlackDrag { get; set; }

        public static void Characters()
        {
            Dash = new Hero("Dash", 3, 10);

            Keith = new Bandit("Keith", 1, 5);
            Leader = new Bandit("Bandit Leader", 2, 8);

            Leeroy = new Knight("Leeroy", 3, 12);
            Seth = new Knight("Seth", 5, 15);

            BlueDrag = new Dragon("Blue Dragon", 7, 20, 2);
            RedDrag = new Dragon("Red Dragon", 8, 20, 3);
            BlackDrag = new Dragon("BlackDrag", 10, 25, 4);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple explanation is that you have made it inaccessible because of your scope / context `{ }`.

Take for example:

```
void Main()
{
    string one = "Hello";

    {
        string two = " World";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(one + two); // will not work
}
```

The reason for this is when you enclose new objects inside a `{ }` it becomes inaccessible outside of it.